# Highcharts Tooltip display different data

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart created using highcharts , where in I am showing list of student names in a class on x axis and average marks obtained on all the  quiz he has taken on the y axis. For example student "abc" had scored 50 and 100 on two tests hence his average is 75. I want 75 to be displayed as value on column chart and on the tool tip i want to display "test 1 - 50","test 2 - 100".So inside series object i am passing in an array of average. Same will be done for other students in class.Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the test values as custom properties and refer to them in tooltip's formatter function:

```
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [{
            y: 75,
            tests: [50, 100]
        }, {
            y: 50,
            tests: [50, 50]
        }]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var str = '';

            this.point.tests.forEach(function(test, i) {
                str += '<br>test' + (i + 1) + ' ' + test;
            });

            return str;
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t5f43zwn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter